# How to fix corrupted blocks?

Tags: bitcoind, raspberry-pi

I am trying to copy blocks from Debian 10 “buster” virtual machine to external SSD which I will boot from on a Raspberry Pi.

```
rsync --archive --delete --human-readable --info=progress2 /home/bitcoin-admin/.bitcoin/ /mnt/usb/home/pi/.bitcoin
        135.53M   0%    9.10MB/s    0:00:14 (xfr#2, ir-chk=7777/8259)
rsync: read errors mapping "/home/bitcoin-admin/.bitcoin/blocks/blk00464.dat": Input/output error (5)
```

Does `rsync` error mean `blk00464.dat` is corrupt? If so, how can I recover?

`bitcoind` runs fine on virtual machine.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: googled the `rsync: read errors mapping`, found this: https://bobcares.com/blog/rsync-input-output-error_5/
`2. Insufficient privileges` -> try `sudo rsync`

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Antoni. The error only occurred for certain blocks and I checked permissions… same for all blocks.

Comment: maybe some sectors on your drive are corrupt. does `dd if=/home/bitcoin-admin/.bitcoin/blocks/blk00464.dat of=/dev/null bs=4K` give any errors?